# In right $\Delta ABC$, $\angle C = 90^\circ$. $E$ is on $BC$ such that $AC = BE$. $D$ is on $AB$ such that $DE \perp BC$ .

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, problem-solving, congruences-geometry

> In right $\Delta ABC$, $\angle C = 90^\circ$. $E$ is on $BC$ such that $AC = BE$. $D$ is on $AB$ such that $DE \perp BC$ . Given that $DE + BC = 1$ and $BD = \frac{1}{2}$, find $\angle B$.

**What I Tried**: Here is a picture :-

[image]

The first try which I think I could do was the Pythagorean Theorem, although I am not sure whether that will help me find $\angle B$. Let $DE = x$, then we have :- $$BE = \sqrt{\frac{1}{4} - x^2}.$$
Now as $AC = BE$, $AC = \sqrt{\frac{1}{4} - x^2}$ too. 
Now, let $CE = y$. What I can do is find $AD$ from similar triangles $BED$ and $BAC$ as well as from Pythagorean Theorem, and then I suppose find the variables $x$ and $y$  but in the end I suppose I am not finding $\angle B$. I also didn't try all this because I think it won't work and is going to be complicated.

Can anyone solve this? I didn't try using Trigonometry because I am a little weak at it, so any solutions without Trigonometry will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $DE=x$, $AC=BE=y$.

$$ \dfrac{DE}{BE} = \dfrac{AC}{BC}$$

$$ \dfrac{x}{y} = \dfrac{y}{1-x}$$

$$ \Rightarrow x = x^2+y^2 = \dfrac{1}{4}$$

$$ \sin B = \dfrac{DE}{BD}=\dfrac{1}{2}$$

$$\therefore \angle B = 30^{\circ}$$

Comment: This is with Trigonometry, any other solutions without Trigonometry? For example, if $\angle B$ comes $30^\circ$ , we can show that only if the value of $DE$ is $\frac{1}{4}$ as it is a $30-60-90$ triangle then. Can we do that? (just asking)

Comment: Given only lengths, it is impossible to determine angle without use of trigonometry. Maybe one can recognize that in a 30-60-90 right triangle, perpendicular is half the hypotenuse since 30-60-90 is half of an equilateral triangle.

Comment: Yes, one may argue like that, which maybe ok for some multiple choice contest. But in rigorous form, trigonometry connects angles and lengths. I suggest not to ignore trigonometry.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let's for simplicity solve an equivalent question,
for the same construction, but twice as large,
for which given constrains are $|BD|=1$, $|DE|+|BC|=2$.

Then clearly,
\begin{align}
|BE|=|AC|&=\cos\beta
,\\
|DE|&=\sin\beta
,\\
|AB|&=\frac{\cos\beta}{\sin\beta}
,\\
|BC|&=\frac{\cos^2\beta}{\sin\beta}
,\\
|DE|+|BC|&=2=
\sin\beta+\frac{\cos^2\beta}{\sin\beta}
=\frac1{\sin\beta}
,\\
\sin\beta&=\tfrac12
,\\
\beta&=30^\circ
.
\end{align}